# How to redirect all .plist file requests to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, friendly-url

I need to edit htaccess special way that all requests i.e. http://www.example.com/supermega.plist or http://www.example.com/ultraturbo.plist will be redirected and generated by one index.php. In index.php I want also read plist filename.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)\.(plist)$ /index.php?filename=$1&ext=$2 [L,QSA]
```

in the following URL :

`http://127.0.0.1/somefilename.plist`

you have access to `filename` and `ext` in `$_GET` :

```
print_r($_GET);
/* output
Array
(
    [filename] => somefilename
    [ext] => plist
)
*/
```

Comment: I had some mistakes.Try it again.

Comment: You are King! It works! 
I would like to add vote up, but I dont have enought reputation ;(

Comment: don't worry. your problem solved and it's more important than upvote. ;)